# How to solve the least squares for A with both X and Y as matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, matrix-calculus, least-squares

I’m trying to solve the following problem: I have a series of n-dimensional vectors x and another of m-dimensional vectors y, so that `y = Ax`, with A being a m,n matrix. I have to solve the least squared problem `||AX-Y||^2` for A. X is a matrix with its columns being x vectors, and the same happens with Y.

The problem I have comes with derivation `||AX-Y||^2`. I am not very experienced with matrix calculus, so I have resorted to doing a sort of reverse engineering approach by creating some matrices of my own and working backwards. I have obtained that the derivative of `||AX-Y||^2 = 2X[AX-Y]`, though I am not really sure if that is the correct result. I have tried searching for any kind of solution online but I have found none. Could someone confirm if what I have is right or wrong and explain to me the proper way to solve it?

Comment: You are close. The gradient is actually $2(AX−Y)X^T$ which you might have eventually figured out by considering the dimensions of the matrices. However, you don't even need that. To solve the problem just multiply by the pseudoinverse $X^+$  to obtain $A=YX^+\;$

Comment: I get it, thank you!